# Unable to login to ClearCanvas, "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"

Tags: dicom, clearcanvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek8b2.jpg)

Hi,

We always encounter this error on every Clearcanvas Server on my company. We tried to restart both mssql and clearcanvas service on Services.msc, and yet the error is reccurring. Our last resort is to restart the server, in which it affect our daily operation.

```
Is their anyway to, solve this problem?
```

Comment: This sounds like a question that needs to be asked from ClearCanvas support.

Answer (score 0):

I have been hit by this a few times. There is a solution, but it is not nice: you have to clear ClearCanvas's primary file system.

1. move everything out of the primary file system folder  `C:\ClearCanvas\FS\Primary` to a temporary folder
2. restart the server and give it some time to process removed studies
3. you should be able to log in again, if not, restart the server and try again
4. bring back studies by moving them in batches from the temporary folder to `C:\ClearCanvas\FS\Primary_Incoming`, from where ClearCanvas will import the files